# Array subscript of nonexistent member of template type passes compilation in g++ 11.3.0

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I found this situation in my recent project. I wanna ask if it is designed as so, what's the underlying mechanism, and how is it useful?

Although I know the subscript in parameters list is somehow useless to compiler, but in my situation, it might be better to raise an error and stop compile.

The source code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

template<typename Type>
class A{
 public:
    // passes compile, although it is not declared
    void print(int data[Type::len]) {  // Line 7
        printf("%d\n", data[0]);
    }

    // error: not declared
    // void print(int data[dummy]) {
    //     printf("%d\n", data[0]);
    // }
};

// error: not declared
// void print(int data[A<double>::len]) {
//         printf("%d\n", data[0]);
// }

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    int x[12] = { 0 };
    a.print(x);  // Line 23
    return 0;
}
```

Compile command using gcc 11.3.0:

```bash
g++ -o a a.cpp -Wall -Wextra
```

No compile output, program prints a "0" and exits with 0.

But in msvc 19.33.31630, it raises [C2825](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2825), [C2510](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2510) on line 7, and [C2670](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2670) on line 23.

Comment: The parameter `data` is actually an `int*`. Still the program should be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an error and that there isn't one is a known bug in GCC.

If the array bound `Type::len` was valid, then the type `int[Type::len]` in the function parameter would be rewritten to `int*` in the instantiation, as is always the case for array types in function parameters. So the actual value of the array bound will not matter from there on out.

However, if `Type::len` is not a valid constant expression with a suitable value for an array bound, then substitution should fail and the program should be ill-formed. In case of `T=int`, `Type::len` is not a valid expression at all and so it should fail to compile (or at least issue some diagnostic). This should happen already at `A<int> a;` (which causes implicit instantiation of `A<int>` including `A<int>::print`'s declaration), even if no actual call to `print` is present.

It seems GCC is performing the rewriting step too early without verifying that the expression in the array bound is actually valid in the substitution.

GCC has a meta-bug report with multiple linked individual bug reports related to this [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24666).